# Reorder Data in Table using jquery each

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have this set of data pulled from the database. The prices are different but some data are redundant.

Here's the screenshot of the data.[image]

The table that I want it to look like is this.

[image]

I arranged them in jQuery using `.each()` but what I got is an epic fail.[image]

Only the header and first body row is correct. Here's my code:

```
var route_price_table = '';
route_price_table = '<table class="table table-bordered table-striped"><thead><tr><th>SEA</th>';
var initial_boxname = '';
var iterator = 0;
var iterator2 = 0;
var length = data.length;
var route_price_body_table = '';
var route_price_body_table2= '';
var initial_routename = '';
$.each( data, function( key, value ) {
            if(iterator == key){
                initial_routename = value.Route;
                route_price_table += '<th>' + value.BoxName + '</th>';
                initial_boxname = value.BoxName;
                if(initial_routename == value.Route){
                    route_price_body_table += '<tr><td>' + value.Route + '</td><td>' + value.Price + ' (' + value.BoxName + ')</td>';
                }
            }
            if(initial_boxname != value.BoxName){
                initial_boxname = value.BoxName;
                route_price_table += '<th>' + value.BoxName + '</th>';
                route_price_body_table += '<td>' + value.Price + ' (' + value.BoxName + ')</td>';
            }
            if(initial_routename != value.Route){
                route_price_body_table2 += '<tr><td>' + value.Route + '</td><td>' + value.Price + ' (' + value.BoxName + ')</td>';
                initial_routename = value.Route;
            }
            if (key === (length - 1)) {
                route_price_table += '</tr></thead><tbody>';
                route_price_table += route_price_body_table + route_price_body_table2;
            }
        });
        route_price_table += '</tbody></table>';
        $('#route_price_table').html(route_price_table);
```

Can this be achieved using jQuery or do I need to just arrange it backend? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: This can be achieved via `jQuery` but I'll suggest you to do it on `backend` so that you don't have to traverse all data again and again.

Comment: @sauhardnc I looked into crosstab query and I think that's what I need but I have no exp in that and I'm still experimenting on that to achieve what I need. It would be awesome if I could be able to set the table headers dynamically using query.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array, grouping items by Route, having all info for each table row in a single object:

```js
let data = [
    {"Price": "10.00", "BoxName": "Small Box", "Route": "NCR/SLuz"},
    {"Price": "15.00", "BoxName": "Small Box", "Route": "NLUZ/VisMin"},
    {"Price": "20.00", "BoxName": "Small Box", "Route": "ISLANDS"},
    {"Price": "25.00", "BoxName": "Small Box", "Route": "Indonesia"},
    {"Price": "30.00", "BoxName": "Medium Box", "Route": "NCR/SLuz"},
    {"Price": "35.00", "BoxName": "Medium Box", "Route": "NLUZ/VisMin"},
    {"Price": "40.00", "BoxName": "Medium Box", "Route": "ISLANDS"},
    {"Price": "45.00", "BoxName": "Medium Box", "Route": "Indonesia"},
    {"Price": "50.00", "BoxName": "Large Box", "Route": "NCR/SLuz"},
    {"Price": "55.00", "BoxName": "Large Box", "Route": "NLUZ/VisMin"},
    {"Price": "60.00", "BoxName": "Large Box", "Route": "ISLANDS"},
    {"Price": "65.00", "BoxName": "Large Box", "Route": "Indonesia"},
    {"Price": "70.00", "BoxName": "Regular Box", "Route": "NCR/SLuz"},
    {"Price": "75.00", "BoxName": "Regular Box", "Route": "NLUZ/VisMin"},
    {"Price": "80.00", "BoxName": "Regular Box", "Route": "ISLANDS"},
    {"Price": "85.00", "BoxName": "Regular Box", "Route": "Indonesia"},
    {"Price": "90.00", "BoxName": "Very Big Box", "Route": "NCR/SLuz"},
    {"Price": "95.00", "BoxName": "Jumbo Box", "Route": "NLUZ/VisMin"},
    {"Price": "100.00", "BoxName": "Jumbo Box", "Route": "ISLANDS"},
    {"Price": "105.00", "BoxName": "Another Box", "Route": "Indonesia"},
];

// .map to get just BoxName and .filter to get unique values
let boxes = data.map((obj) => obj.BoxName).filter((v, i, a) => a.indexOf(v) === i);

// Define a new object to reorder items
let nData = {};

// Loop on original array
$.each(data, (key, item) => {
    // Check if exists current Route
    if(!nData[item.Route]) {
        // Initialize as empty object
        nData[item.Route] = {};
    }
    // Assign Price to BoxName
    nData[item.Route][item.BoxName] = item.Price;
});

// Now you can use boxes for table head and loop nData to build the table
console.log(boxes, nData);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution! The box types are not fixed so when I tried what you did, those who are not equal to names: Small Medium Large Regular Jumbo were not included. I need it to be dynamic.