# MySQL Use dynamic row values as column names

Tags: mysql, sql, codeigniter, crosstab, group-concat

I have this set of data (view table) that I built out of multiple tables.[image]

My problem is, I can't display them in a 'horizontal' way. I searched and found several solutions but they're now [outdated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977322/mysql-select-specific-row-values-as-column-names?noredirect=1&lq=1).

They use pivot table or crosstab query or group_concat().

So what I need as a result, the dynamic BoxName will be a column name and the price will be under each. And then the Route will be the row headers.

My Goal:

[image]

I tried manipulating the data via [jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62963689/reorder-data-in-table-using-jquery-each?noredirect=1#comment111346222_62963689) but I failed so my last resort is to fix the MySQL data so the jQuery display will be easy.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It still works in mysql 8 and if you don't use mysql 8 cte's will not work with prior mysql version, also don't post pictures for data

Comment: You'll can do it two steps: 1) Get the variants, i.e. the columns names using a simple query. 2) Using dynamic SQL you can assemble the query that will produce the table you want.

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in application code

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) [mre]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Step #1**: Get the column names:

```
select distinct BoxName from t
```

For example, this query will return:

```
BoxName
-----------
Small Box    
Medium Box
Large Box
Regular Box
Jumbo Box
```

**Step #2**: Assemble a dynamic query. Now that you know the columns you can prepare the main query as:

```
select
  Route,
  max(case when BoxName = 'Small Box' then price end) as `Small Box`,
  max(case when BoxName = 'Medium Box' then price end) as `Medium Box`,
  max(case when BoxName = 'Large Box' then price end) as `Large Box`,
  max(case when BoxName = 'Regular Box' then price end) as `Regular Box`,
  max(case when BoxName = 'Jumbo Box' then price end) as `Jumbo Box`
from t
group by Route
order by max(display_order)
```